# How to edit Aerial Faith Plate trajectory?

Tags: portal-2, hammer

So, I have this map that has a pretty low ceiling and a hidden aeriel faith plate.

Whenever the faith plate gets triggered, my head hits the ceiling. I have a lot of panels and other stuff set up and it would be a pain to make the ceiling higher.

Is there any other way to lower the maximum height of the aeriel faith plate's trajectory? or is making the ceiling higher the only way?

Comment: Nevermind, I Figured it out.

Comment: You should post what you learned as an answer for future players who may have the same question.

Comment: @AdamV I assume it has something to do with threshold settings for the `trigger_catapult`, but I'm just going by the [Valve Developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Faith_Plate).

Answer (score -2):

I think that I have an answer for your question. Are you making a faith plate that shoots directly up?

If you are, you can have another trigger catapult above the ceiling which would shoot directly down. This should solve it. Make the speed smaller than of the first one, so it looks more natural.